# werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'id'

Tags: rest, flask, post

html page

```
{%block title%}Login page{% endblock %}

{%block content%}
<form action = '#' method="post">
   <p>creds:</p>
   <p><input type="number"  placeholder="id"  Id="id" /></p>
   <p><input type="text"  placeholder="nm"  name="nm" /></p>
   <p><input type="submit" value="submit" /></p>
</form>
{%endblock%}
```

app code

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("login.html")

@app.route("/",methods = ["POST","GET"])
def post():
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.form['nm']
        id = request.form['id']
        sql = ('''INSERT INTO abc
                (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)
                ''')
        val = (id,user)
        cur.execute (sql, val)
    return 'Ok'
```

I tried using `return.form.get('id')`, but its returning null.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<p><input type="number"  placeholder="id"  name="id" /></p>
```

you have typed Id instead of name

Answer (score 6):

When you use `request.form["something"]` you assume that this something always be part of your request, I recommend you to use `request.form.get("something", False)` to avoid that error. I hope this will solve your doubts.

Comment: Hours of trying to fix this and searching everywhere ... I see you wrote request.form.get("something") instead of me using request.form["something"] when I was using $.post in jQuery. My hours of pain has ended thanks to you! :) -Python newbie

Comment: Thank you so much  .Your answer "equest.form.get("something", False)" working to me .

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem, but mine was with a "`SelectField`" , the update fields would be "None" and to avoid that I just added option value None as shown below:

```
<option value="None">None</option>
```

This fixed my problem